# Spring Boot Native SQL query with pagination not working

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am stuck with one native SQL query in `spring boot` application. I am not able to judge what is the problem because it is working fine in my localhost environment but I am getting exception in production. Below is my `JPA Repository` method with query:

```
@Query(value = "select date(start_date) as DATEE, sum(case when subscription_from in ('IVR','SMS') and remarks like '%Change Song%' then 1 else 0 end) as song_change from subscription group by date(start_date) \n#pageable\n", nativeQuery=true)
    Page<Object[]> getSongChangeCount2(Pageable page);
```

Below is the exception I am getting on production:

```
2019-09-25 07:39:18.397  WARN 12080 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2019-09-25 07:39:18.397 ERROR 12080 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group) from subscription group by date(start_date)
#pageable' at line 1
2019-09-25 07:39:18.400 ERROR 12080 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/crbt/api/v1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group) from subscription group by date(start_date)
#pageable' at line 1
```

In localhost its working fine. I am getting desired output on browser..here:

[image]

Can you tell where am I wrong...What can I do to resolve this issue.

also to note : **without pagination its working fine on production too.**

I am using **1.5.9.RELEASE** spring boot version.

Comment: The error is weird, since there is no `group)  from subscription` in your query  .

Comment: I have tested it using `System.out.println()` statements to know where the flow is getting break.. It is at this point only i.e. at repository method.

Comment: The MySQL in the production environment must be an older version...

Comment: Check your MySQL version in your production environment which might be older. If the project run in localhost, it should work

Comment: my localhost mysql version is : Server version: 5.5.54 MySQL Community Server (GPL)    and  production mysql version is mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.62, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1... is there any version related issue?

Comment: springboot application is using -- mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar

Comment: without pagination its working fine on production environment too

Comment: maybe the generated count query is wrong. try to define a count query manually.
You can set this via the @Query annotation 
See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query for more information (section 4. Pagination)